# Usb devices stop working as soon as applications access powered usb webcam

Tags: usb, camera

My mouse and keyboard stop working when i plug in my webcam.

I use a docking station. Now as soon as I plug in the camera to the docking station and start an app that streams the webcam image, the other devices stop working (mouse and camera). If I plug either of them directly into my laptop they work again.

I initially thought this was a power issue. So I attached a powered USB hub to my docking station and put the camera into this USB hub.
It did not work so I assume it is not a power issue. Any thoughts on what the issue could be?
This is the usb-devices output for camera and mouse

```
T:  Bus=03 Lev=03 Prnt=09 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 14 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=32 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=03f0 ProdID=a407 Rev=03.21
S:  Manufacturer=HP
S:  Product=HP Link-5 micro dongle
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=03 Lev=03 Prnt=09 Port=02 Cnt=02 Dev#= 12 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=145f ProdID=0203 Rev=00.05
S:  Manufacturer=Sunplus IT Co 
S:  Product=Trust USB Camera
S:  SerialNumber=20200707002
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
```

Again, the devices connected to the dock (via a powered USB hub) stop working as soon as an application actually uses the webcam and not before. Any tips how I could go further with debugging or solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could still be a power issue, since your powered USB hub still draws some current out of the docking station. Have you tried getting rid of the docking station and using only the powered USB hub?

Comment: Getting rid of the docking station is not really a viable solution for me. I have two monitors on there. I'd rather just want the dock to work.